# why logarithmic p-holomorphic forms are closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am readding one proof of Bogomolov-–Sommese vanishing theorem, and they use that for any $s\in \Omega^p_X(D)$ we have $ds=0.$
Here $D$ is an effective divisor of $Y$:= Complex algebraic manifold.

So, I want to know why the logarithmic p-holomorphic forms are closed?

In the following paper arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110051.pdf theorem 2.24 said : By Hodge theory ($X$ being K¨ahler, or even just in $C\mathbb{C}$), the holomorphic $p$-forms $s_i$ ,$i=0,...,p$ on $X$ are closed. And something similar is used for logarithmic p−holomorphic forms.

Any help, is amazing!

Comment: There's a decent chance that it's a dimension bound based on $\Omega_X^{p+1}(D)=0$. Without knowing what $p$ is, it's hard to say. Could you clarify what $p$ is?

Comment: When I said p-holomorphic form, it refers to $(p,0)-$forms, and $\overline{\partial}s=0$

Comment: Sure, but do you mean all $p$-forms, or some specific value of $p$? You should perhaps edit your question so that the information in your comment is available there.

Comment: In the following paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110051.pdf theorem 2.24 said :    By Hodge theory (X being K¨ahler, or even just in $\mathbb{C}$), the holomorphic $p$-forms $s_i$ ,$i = 0,...,p$ on $X$ are closed.                                   And something similar is used for logarithmic $p-$holomorphic forms.